# Javascript regular expression for Mmm-DD-YYYY

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am working on a class assignment which works with dates.

if the user gives the date as "Jan-12-2000", I want to check it's pattern. I tried a lot but couldn't make it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) *"I tried a lot but couldn't make it."* What did those attempts look like? In what way did they not work? What part of it are you stuck on?

Answer (score 0):

First replace the shortforms of the month with its corresponding value:

```
check=string=>{
 string=string.split("-");    
 date=[
   string[2],
   ["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"].indexOf(string[0])+1,
   string[1]
  ];
  console.log(date.join("-"));
  return !isNaN(+new Date(date.join("-")));
  }
```

This just works for correct dates...

```
check("Jan-31-2000");//true
check("Jan-32-2000");//false
```

http://jsbin.com/kuyuxiwufu/edit?console

Answer (score 0):

Reg breakdown

- `[A-Z][a-z]{2}` find a capitalized three letter word
- `\d{2}` find two digits
- `\d{4}` find four digits

```js
const reg = /[A-Z][a-z]{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}/

console.log(
  reg.test('Jan-12-2000'), // pass
  reg.test('01-10-2000')   // fail
)
```